# CRM Destination not showing all the fields in column in kingswaysoft

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, kingswaysoft

I am facing an issue while I am mapping the column fields CRM Source to CRM destination in Kingswaysoft. I am Migrating data for mailbox entity but Destination column is not showing all the fields which are present for mailbox entity.

Could anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our software is metadata-driven, we only show the fields in the destination component that are applicable to the action type that you have chosen. Keep in mind, many of CRM fields are readonly such as those lookup name, option set name fields, etc.